# Using beautiful soup to scrape data from indeed

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am trying to use bs to scrape resume on indeed but i met some problems
here is the sample site: https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=java&l=&cb=jt

here is my code:

```
URL = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=java&l=&cb=jt"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

def scrape_job_title(soup): 
    job = []
    for div in soup.find_all(name='li', attrs={'class':'sre'}):
        for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'class':'app-link'}):
            job.append(a['title'])
        return(job)
scrape_job_title(soup)
```

it print out nothing: []

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I want to grab the job title "Java developer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is `app_link`, not `app-link`.  Additionally, `a['title']` doesn't do what you want.  Use `a.contents[0]` instead.

```
URL = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=java&l=&cb=jt"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

def scrape_job_title(soup): 
    job = []
    for div in soup.find_all(name='li', attrs={'class':'sre'}):
        for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'class':'app_link'}):
        job.append(a.contents[0])
    return(job)

scrape_job_title(soup)
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was a stupid mistake for that underscore,
does 'a.contents[o]' means grab the fist string in tag <a>?

Comment: why there is a letter 'u' in front each element? What does it mean? How to remove it?

Comment: It just means that it's unicode. You probably don't have to worry about it.  You can just imagine that it's the same as a regular string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get all the job titles:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.indeed.com/resumes?q=java&l=&cb=jt"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html5lib')

for items in soup.select('.sre'):
    data = [item.text for item in items.select('.app_link')]
    print(data)
```